# Python load timer

Tags: python-3.x, time, tkinter

What I have is the code that should (object btw) create a loading percentage that updates every 0.01 seconds for example
1%
2%
3%
except just one line with the percent increasing every 0.01 seconds.

BUT:

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
text = Listbox(root)
text.insert(END, "Loading : ")
text.pack()
import time
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
def sleep():
    time.sleep(0.01)
def start():
    i = 0
    for i in range(101):
        text.delete(0, END)
        next
        sleep()
        text.insert(END, i)          
        i+1
start()
root.mainloop()
```

it simply waits in the console for 100 x 0.01 seconds then inserts texts on the object as what it should be as a final (100%)

This works in python 2.4.1
im now using 3.4.2

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Just glancing at your code `i+1`? Should it not be i+=1?

Comment: That isn't the problem. The code works fine. But what it will not do is display all the percentage changes as they happen. instead it does all the waiting first. Then displays the end result. What I want is to show it getting from 1% to 100%.

Comment: don't ever use `time.sleep()` in a GUI thread, [use root.after() to implement the timer instead](https://gist.github.com/zed/5440b9372a15d86b5c47)